# Does Google App Engine support Python 3?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I started learning **Python 3.4** and would like to start using libraries as well as **Google App Engine**, but the majority of **Python** libraries only support **Python 2.7** and the same with **Google App Engine**.

Should I learn **2.7** instead or is there an easier way? (Is it possible to have 2 Python versions on my machine at the same time?)

Comment: There isn't much difference between Python 2.x+ and Python 3.x+, so you might as well learn Python 2.x+. You can have more than one version of Python on a machine at the same time, but the only way to use Python 3 with App Engine at the moment is by using the "Managed VMs" feature: https://developers.google.com/cloud/managed-vms

Comment: Google's internal issue for GAE Py3k support: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=909

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No, It doesn't.**

*[Editor's note: As of Aug, 2018, this answer is outdated; see comments and other answers]*

`Google App Engine` `(GAE)` uses sandboxed `Python 2.7` runtime for `Python` applications. That is the normal **App Engine Hosting**. However, in `GAE` you can use [**Managed VM Hosting**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

The **Managed VM Hosting** lets you run `GAE` applications on configurable **Google Compute Engine Virtual Machines**. Giving you more flexibility. **Managed VMs** at the moment ,at Alpha phase, only support `Java 7`, `Python 2.7` and `Go 1.4` runtime environments. To get other runtimes (like `Python 3` or `node.js`) you can create [user-configurable custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

**Note:** With **Managed VM**s you won't have the capabilities of `Python 2.7` **GAE** libraries.

- *If you insist on using **GAE***, since `Python 3+` is not viable, I would suggest learning **2.7** and switching to **3+** versions when **GAE** libraries gets ported to `Python 3+`. You can easily switch to the other if you learn one of the versions.
- *If you insist on using `Python 3+`*, you can use [**Heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) or [**Microsoft Azure**](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/python/). Both of them supports `Python 2.7` and `3.4`.

Comment: **GAE Update**: Managed VM Hosting now natively supports Python 3.4 out of the box and is in public beta (not alpha).

Comment: Though you can't (yet) use any of the google app engine libraries with
 python3. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app

Comment: Yes, it does since August 10, 2016. Check Google Cloud Platform blog https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/08/python-3-on-Google-App-Engine-flexible-environment-now-in-beta.html

Comment: Standard edition supports 3.7 now: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-app-engine-second-generation-runtimes-and-python-3-7

Answer (score 28):

[**Since August 10, 2016, it does.**](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/08/python-3-on-Google-App-Engine-flexible-environment-now-in-beta.html)

If you are using [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) beta environment, you can edit your application [`app.yaml`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/hello_world/app.yaml) and specify the required Python version:

```
runtime: python
# vm: true has been deprecated
# check how env:flex may affect your billing
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

Comment: Can you show a proper diff of the default file with your customized file?

Comment: As of Nov 2016, GAE does not support 3.5, just 3.4. And 3.6 is just around the corner.

Comment: [3.5.2 is supported (on December 2016)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) it is the version Ubuntu 16.04LTS manages in their repos.

Comment: vm:true has been deprecated and should be replaced with env:flex.   Also this setting has billing repercussions that users should be aware of.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Python 3.7 is available as a Google App Engine standard runtime [as of August 8, 2018](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-app-engine-second-generation-runtimes-and-python-3-7).

Answer (score 1):

YES! Google App engine supports python v3, you need to set up flexible environments.

I got a chance to deploy my application on app engine and It's using python 3.6 runtime and works smoothly... :)

Answer (score 1):

**(Jun 2021)**: It's been more than 7 years, and many answers here are either incorrect or partially correct. At the time of this writing, Python 3 is fully-supported by all [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) products. Here are the supported versions, links to the documentation, and launch announcements:

1. **[App Engine - Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard)** ([Aug 2018](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-app-engine-second-generation-runtimes-and-python-3-7)): Python [2.7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Selecting_the_runtime) and [3.7, 3.8, 3.9](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#python_3_versions)
2. **[App Engine - Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible)** ([Aug 2016 beta](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/python-3-on-google-app-engine-flexible-environment-now-in-beta), [Mar 2017 GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/your-favorite-languages-now-on-google-app-engine)): [Python 3.7(.2)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#interpreter)

Another change since the OP is that [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com) launched 2 more [serverless compute platforms](https://cloud.google.com/serverless), joining App Engine, and both support Python 3 as well:

1. **[Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions)** ([Mar 2017 beta](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-your-next-home-in-the-cloud), [Aug 2018 GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/cloud-functions-serverless-platform-is-generally-available)): *supports same versions as App Engine - Standard*
2. **[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)** ([Apr 2019 beta](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/announcing-cloud-run-the-newest-member-of-our-serverless-compute-stack), [Nov 2019 GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/knative-based-cloud-run-services-are-ga)): *any version you can put in a container*

Answer (score 0):

Google App engine support python runtimes up to versions python v3.7 (till today).

Python v3.7 runtime fully supported by standard environment. (Non-flexible environment) and PiP packages in requirements.txt is also supported by standard runtime, will automatically install dependencies declared in requirements.txt.

*app.yaml* configuration for Python v3.7 follows below.

```
runtime: python37 
entrypoint: as you required.
```

It's not required include *runtime_config* in app.yaml for python v3.7 standard environment.

Answer (score -1):

In the standard environment, vendoring was necessary to install third-party libraries. This task is not needed in the flexible environment as the runtime will automatically install dependencies declared in requirements.txt, including dependencies that require native extensions.

> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app#behavioral_differences