# Python 3 for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.x

I've started an App Engine Project with Python 2.7 but had already be used to working on Python 3.

Does anyone know if there are any plans for Google's App Engine to work with Python 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google App Engine support Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229203/does-google-app-engine-support-python-3)

Answer (score 3):

App Engine's new (and currently beta) [Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) supports Python 3.4.

Comment: _This is a Beta release of the App Engine flexible environment. It is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and the implementation may change, possibly in backward-incompatible ways. It is not recommended for production use._

Comment: True. And the answer mentions it in beta. Also, the question was about what plans there are for future support, of which a beta is a strong answer.

Answer (score 3):

On August 10, 2016, [Google Cloud Platform Blog](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/08/python-3-on-Google-App-Engine-flexible-environment-now-in-beta.html) announced that Python 3 was in beta on Google App Engine:

> *Developers running Python on Google App Engine have long asked for support for Python 3 and third-party Python packages. Today we're excited to announce the beta release of the Python runtime on App Engine Flexible Environment with support for Python 3.4 and 2.7. You can now develop applications in the Python version you prefer and create performant mobile and web backends using the frameworks and libraries of your choice. Meanwhile, developers benefit from App Engine's built-in services, such as autoscaling, load balancing, microservices support and traffic splitting and hence can focus on their code and not worry about infrastructure maintenance.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are plans, see

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=909

(well, it's not really a concrete plan, but its an open issue and Google has acknowledged it's existance)

However, because Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x are quite similar, the priority to implement Python 3.x support from Google's perspective isn't very high. It's likely a massive amount of work to support it, and it isn't really a critical issue. Don't expect Python 3.x to be supported anytime soon.

Comment: Dont count on it. Use GCE

Comment: @ZigMandel I think you meant to comment on the question?

Comment: I guess. Thou its not bad here as a complement to the answer. With all the work google is doing with containers and integration with appengine, its clear that python 3 support will be on that route and not directly in appengine itself.

Comment: In the meantime, a [managed vm](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/#custom_runtimes) *might* be an option if you want auto-scaling, but you'll have to use the REST APIs instead of the built-in APIs for Datastore, Task Queues, etc. It depends how much of a reliance you have on Python 3 really.