# Fail to get 'Try Google App Engine Now' to work

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have download and installed GoogleCloudSDK and I did the following commands:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud components update gae-python
```

And I downloaded the Django started code from the link proposed ([*](https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/_ah/mimic/ziprepo?repo=repos/appengine-try-python-django&filename=appengine-try-python-django.zip)), then unpacked it and used `cd` to get into the unpacked zip file folder. Then I try to run `appcfg.py -A #myprojectidhere` and I get this error:

```
C:\Users\THOMAS\Downloads\appengine-try-python-django>appcfg.py -A #myprojectidhere
er-544
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\appcfg.py", line
8, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\boo
tstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
    import setup
ImportError: No module named 'setup'
```

I fail to understand why i'm getting this, any help?

Comment: Hey! I don't know for you, but I see a "setup.py" file in the same folder as bootstrapping, no? In any case, could it just be some edit to your PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check if you have python 2.7 in use, because Google App Engine does not work with python 3.x.

[Does Google App Engine support Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229203/does-google-app-engine-support-python-3)

Comment: I think that might be the problem, weird how Google prefers 2.7 over 3.4