# Backporting from 3 to 2.7: ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, backport

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229203/does-google-app-engine-support-python-3), and crying a lot, I'm trying to make my Django app work with Python 2.7.

Here's my Django web dir:

```
├── locale
│   ├── en
│   ├── fr
│   └── sv
├── produits
│   ├── migrations
│   └── templatetags
├── pyweb
├── templates
│   └── produits
├── third_party
│   ├── authomatic_0_1_0
│   ├── defusedxml-0.4.1
│   ├── google_appengine_1_9_25
│   ├── python-openid_2_2_5
│   └── python3-openid
└── uploads
```

The most important to notice is that I've tried to add all my "external" module into a folder `third_party`.

In my `views.py`, the following code was working:

```
from third_party.authomatic_0_1_0 import authomatic
from third_party.authomatic_0_1_0.authomatic import adapters
from third_party.authomatic_0_1_0.authomatic.providers import oauth1, oauth2
```

It was working ***because I added those lines*** in `settings.py` at the very beginning:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR+'/third_party/defusedxml-0.4.1')
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR+'/third_party/python3-openid')
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR+'/third_party/google_appengine_1_9_25')
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR+'/third_party/authomatic_0_1_0')
```

But now, with python 2.7 it doesnt work anymore. What should I do to make it work? And what is a good practice in Python (because Pycharm doesn't recognize all the subfolders of `third_party`)?

Comment: Have you considered adding an `__init__.py` to make `third_party` into a package? Presumably each sub-directory already is one?

Comment: Can you please post the full error you get?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You found the error! May I ask you to answer it and I'll check as valid? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems: (1) encoding, so I added in all files at the very beginning:

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

(2) Decorator `python_2_unicode_compatible`: needed this for all my models with `__str__` implemented, for example:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Texte(models.Model):
    texte = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.texte
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#s-module-django.utils.encoding) for more information